# Images in front of nivo-slider is cut

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using nivo-slider in my web Application, I added an image in front of the slider, but this image is cut when the slider moves from image to image.

you can see this problem here: http://www.darelnadwa.com/egyfantasy/

**Edit:** I solved the problem by adding z-index to the image in front of the slide. I gave it z-index: 10;

Comment: Works fine for me, although the website is ungodly slow to load. Edit: The site took more time to load than for me to think of and write this comment. And this edit to it.

Comment: It didn't work for me... and then it worked... weird... ?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my personal server, and my Internet speed is a bit slow!

Comment: Look like it works for me, you have the slider in the header region and, there's no cut of image

Comment: I resolved the problem, I'll edit this question.

Comment: In order to properly mark a question as answered/solved, write your answer as an answer to this question (below) and accept it. This will remove your question from the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding z-index to the image in front of the slide. I gave it z-index: 10;